# Assign all desktops?

Tags: itunes, macos

I'm trying some of the tips from the Cult of Mac iTunes 11 tips [blog post](http://www.cultofmac.com/203679/the-ultimate-list-of-itunes-11-tips-tricks-and-changes-roundup/). I don't see *Options > Assign To > All Desktops* when I right click my iTunes 11 icon. Any ideas? Using OSX 10.8.2, that matters.

> Here’s a nifty tip for using iTunes 11 in multiple Spaces or monitors: right click the iTunes icon in your dock and select Options > Assign To > All Desktops. Now when you use iTunes in full screen mode, you can also open the MiniPlayer separately and have it run in a different space or monitor. So you could have iTunes running full screen on your big external monitor while the MiniPlayer is on your laptop screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: On my Lion machine, I still have that option, but there are definitely some bugs in iTunes 11, so perhaps it doesn't show up for some configurations.

Comment: I'm on ML and don't see the option either

Comment: for me it is working under ML - do you have spaces activated?

Comment: Yes, thought of that first.

Answer (score 3):

Killing dock a couple times seemed to fix the problem:

```
killall Dock
```

In case Dock doesn't get restarted automatically run

```
sudo launchctl load System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Dock.plist
sudo launchctl start com.apple.Dock.agent
```

Comment: Yep, same here.